# Path on image view android for multiple screen?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I use path to draw line on image view but when i run app in tablet the coordinates correct but when i run app in mobile device the coordinate not correct the phone give me smaller shap can any tell me how to solve this.

Comment: what shape you want to draw? post the image that u created for tablet?

Comment: how can i add the image here ?? this site give me error